# how to save file in binary format in db?

Tags: php, mysql, binaryfiles

I need to save files in binary format in my database rather than saving files in directory and inserting file name in the database. Like i get the file  by `print_r($_FILES)` and what is next now??

Comment: You can store your full file access url . But i recommanded to you store only file name and then trying to access your file through your uploaded folder and Table record

Comment: While you can store binary files with a `BLOB` types on a column its generally a bad idea. Filesystems are good for storing files. Databases are good for storing data.

Comment: thanks for idea, but i want to know about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table entity data type should be blob

```
  CREATE TABLE `media`( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `content` BLOB, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

For Example :

```
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

      $fileContent = file_get_contents($uploadfile);
      $query = "INSERT INTO `media` (content) VALUES ("$fileContent");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column with type blob in your database table.
Then get the file content using file_get_contents($uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
now store it in database column easily by using insertion query.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others